# addEventListener repeats itself

Tags: javascript

I click `<a>`, it shows its id, but if I click the `<a>` again, it shows `alert()`twice, if I click it again, it shows `alert()` 3 times and it goes like that. How can I prevent repeating itself?

```
<a id="5" class="accRoom" onclick="dynamicLink()">5</a>
<a id="6" class="accRoom" onclick="dynamicLink()">6</a>
```

`dynamicLink()`function in a .js folder

```
function dynamicLink() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("accRoom");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert(this.id);
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about not attaching a new event listener whenever the event listener is invoked?

Comment: becuase every time you click on the `<a>` tag you add a new eventListener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happen because everytime you click your script will attach the click event to all the elements with class `accRoom`, you've just to attach the click one time :

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("accRoom");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(this.id);
    }, false);
}
```

Then the html should looks like :

```
<a id="5" class="accRoom">5</a>
<a id="6" class="accRoom">6</a>
```

Hope will help you.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("accRoom");

function eventFunction() {
  alert(this.id);
}
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].removeEventListener('click',eventFunction,false);
  x[i].addEventListener("click",eventFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<a id="5" class="accRoom">5</a>
<a id="6" class="accRoom">6</a>
```

Or you could just send the clicked element as object `this` to the function onclick :

```js
//This link was added dynamically
document.body.innerHTML += '<a id="7" class="accRoom" onclick="dynamicLink(this)">7</a>';

function dynamicLink(_this) {
  alert(_this.id);
}
```

```html
<a id="5" class="accRoom" onclick="dynamicLink(this)">5</a>
<a id="6" class="accRoom" onclick="dynamicLink(this)">6</a>
```

Comment: I am creating <a> link dynamically from ajax. I wanted to put the code in a function because If I don't put it in a function, var x is always empty. The code doesn't work if I don't put it in a function.

Comment: try now I changed the code so every time you create a link it will remove the event from all element then add it again this is how you don't have duplicated events

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The function `dynamicLink` is attaching an anonymous function (that does an alert) to the click event of every element with CSS class 'accRoom'.

The problem is that it is also attached to the click event. So each time you click it will attach another function to the click event, and so...

you can avoid that behaviour by removing the `onclick` attribute on 'accRoom' links and calling `dynamicLink` after the dom is loaded.

HTML:

```
<a id="5" class="accRoom">5</a>
<a id="6" class="accRoom">6</a>
```

JS:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("accRoom");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(this.id);
    }, false);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", addDynamicLinks)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Don't use anonymous function

```
function awesomeAlert(){
   alert(this.id);
}

function dynamicLink() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("accRoom");
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].removeEventListener("click", awesomeAlert);
        x[i].addEventListener("click", awesomeAlert, false);
    }
}
```

Maybe you don't care but there are a lot of better ways to set listeners, and in the code above there is room to improve and that is another story.

Have fun